# How to debug nodejs with a full url?

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I've installed node-inspector and express, and succeeded to start debugging with the url http://{localhost}:8080/debug?port=5858.

But I'm developping a static file server, and want to verify how the code is running when the request comes from http://{localhost}:8080/javascript/abc.js. How can I do that? What is the correct url in this case?

Comment: I'd guess from the first URL that http://localhost:8080 is your node-inspector server instance. Is the URL in the second paragraph a mistake? Your server will be running elsewhere, e.g. port 3000 is the default for an express app. I think you may be connecting to the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your express application is listening on port 3000:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
express.listen(3000);
```

and your Node-Inspector is listening on 8080 as you mentioned in your question.

How to step through the code handling a request for a static file:

1. Open Node Inspector in the first browser tab (`http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`).
2. Set a breakpoint in the static file handler. If you are using `express.static`, then you need to find this file:

   ```
   node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js
   ```

   Shortcut: press Ctrl+O (Cmd+O on Mac) and type `static.js` to the search box.
3. Open your application in **another browser tab** (`http://localhost:8080/javascript/abc.js`).
4. The browser should show progress and be waiting for the response from the server. The response is not coming because the server is stopped at a breakpoint.
5. Switch to the first tab with Node Inspector and do your debugging.